# Similar configuration of cookies of web.xml in Apache

Tags: apache, cookies, web.xml

I'm trying to change the configuration of cookies from my **web.xml** of my application and use it in the Apache Server in **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd_proxy.conf**.

**Web.xml**

```
<cookie-config>
    <path>/</path>
</cookie-config>
```

So how can i configure my Apache_Server to get the same effect.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the same effect of the `/` of web.xml in Apache, you should to make sure to specify a name of cookie in your `web.xml` like so:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <name>name_of_cookie</name>
        <path>/</path>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Then in your server Apache in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd_proxy.conf` file you need to specify the name of cookie like so:

```
ProxyPass / balancer://Appcluster/ stickysession=name_of_cookie
```

If you are using multiple cookies of a cookie per application you need to specify them in each application like before in web.xml and you can separate them with a | in your Apache `httpd_proxy.conf` file like this:

```
ProxyPass / balancer://Appcluster/ stickysession=name_of_cookie1|name_of_cookie2|name_of_cookieN
```